# Combining several inputs to a single headphone output?

Tags: headphones, mixer, preamp, input, pre-amp

I use in-ears on stage and was wondering if there are any headphone amps that support several inputs to a single output?

- Input 1 (jack)
- Input 2 (jack)
- Output 1 (jack)

Basically my end game is that I get click tracks and backingtracks from a computer on stage. This is sent directly to my in-ears. However, I want to be able to send my own vocals and guitars to my in-ears as well. So I was thinking a headphone amp with more than one input. So I can get my vocals and guitars back from the front of house mixer and back to my ears.

Anyone know if such a device exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a theatre technician for a multitude of shows that involve everything from bands to 60 people musicals, you have a few options. You can go with a mixer as mentioned above or you can use something a little more high tech like a Pre-Sonus / Studio Live sound board that'll do it all including your in-ear monitors with iPad control, each band member can have their own iPads or you can all share one. Why would you each use a tablet? You can lock individual tablets to individual musicians. Basically how I'd do it: MacMini >Firewire> Pre-Sonus Board > WiFi > iPad. They all connect and you'll get the best sound from such a setup. Sounds like you probably have everything you need to get started except a mixer or the better option your own board, which every venu should have sound equipment but so should most musicians and bands for their own home studio.

On the cheap? Use a virtual audio device. E.g. combine multiple inputs as one virtual microphone. This is known as an Aggregate Audio Device on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a mixer (before the headphone amp) to control what and how much goes into your in-ears. In live situations this is a very simple task for a monitor engineer but if there isn't one, the FOH engineer could send you a mix of what you need (clicks, guitar and vocals) if he has a spare auxiliary out and a spare line on his multi.

Answer (score 1):

I just want add to the other answer that there are such things as headphone mixers. These are cool because you can set the unit out in the live Room with the musicians and they can set their own levels. This is so great as an engineer, because sometimes getting the mix for their headphones can be a long painful process.

A headphone mixer might be just what you need.

Behringer makes one called the "MicroAMP HA400 4-Ch Headphone Amplifier"